# Multicolumn in tcolorbox+tabularx breaks if on the first line

Tags: errors, tabularx, tcolorbox, multicol

I'm using `tcolorbox` with `tabularx` and `multicol` to recreate a form. This works fine but when I try to use a `multicolumn` in the very first row, I get the following error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan
```

This does not happen when the multicolumn is preceded by a "normal" line and searching for the error does not produce any relevant solutions. I can circumvent this problem if I move the content of the first row into a `title=` of tabularx, but if I have two such rows, this hack doesn't work any more.

I made this minimal, reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X}]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{helloworld}\\ % <--- error here
hello & world\\                  % <--- this seems fine
\multicolumn{2}{c}{helloworld}   % <--- this seems fine
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I compile this with `pdflatex test.tex`.

**Edit:** I can confirm that the problem does not exist when using tabularx alone:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{helloworld}\\ % <--- this is fine now
hello & world\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{helloworld}
\end{tabularx}
```

This means it must have to do with tcolorbox.

Comment: I get no error, are your packages up to date ? `tabularx` v2.11 and `tcolorbox` v4.20 for instance ?

Comment: I have tabularx v2.11 and tcolorbox v4.15. Perhaps this is it. I'll check how to upgrade and see if the upgrade of tcolorbox solves this.

Comment: Using `tcolorbox` v 4.20 (2019.03.19) works fine. Update your LaTeX installation!

Comment: Yes, it was an outdated package. However, I think a workaround for older versions might be useful.

Comment: Workaround was done inside new versions of package :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating packages